# I have my constructor class written, but I need to test it. How do I do that?

Tags: java, class-constructors

I'm a relatively new Java programmer, and I'm working on learning Constructors. I've gotten the format of how to make the Constructor itself down, but my Computer Science teacher requires me to write some more lines of code that will make sure my Constructor works.

I've looked on other sites, and it doesn't really give me what I need.

I've tried using what I thought might logically work (typing "a.variable()" as an object, but that didn't work either.

```
class Car {
    public String make;
    public String model;
    public int numberOfDoors;
    public int topSpeed;
    public int price;

    Car(String make, String model, int numberOfDoors, int topSpeed, int price){
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
        this.price = price;
    }

    Car(String make, String model, int topSpeed, int price){
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.numberOfDoors = 4;
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
        this.price = price;
    }

    Car(int numberOfDoors, int topSpeed, int price){
        this.make = "unknown";
        this.model = "unknown";
        this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
        this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
        this.price = price;
    }

    Car(String make, String model, int numberOfDoors){
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
        this.topSpeed = 90;
        this.price = 0;
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something that will print out something like:

1990 Mustang, 4 doors, 140 mph, $40000

Comment: And before anyone says anything, yes, I am aware of the technical errors I made while converting my code and things to StackOverflow...

Comment: To access a public field of an object, the syntax is `a.variable`, not `a.variable()`.  The parentheses are used for invoking methods, and your class has no methods.

Comment: You should (typically) only have one constructor that actually does the real work: the other overloads should just call `this(....)`, forwarding parameters and supplying defaults for omitted parameters.

Comment: "I am aware of the technical errors I made while converting my code and things to StackOverflow" if you're aware, could you fix them?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to create an instance of the class `Car` using an appropriate constructor.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car("Mustang", "1990", 4, 140, 40000);
    }
}
```

With the instance `car` created, you can access its fields.

For example,

```
int numberOfDoors = car.numberOfDoors;
```

We usually make fields private and access them via getters:

```
int numberOfDoors = car.getNumberOfDoors();
```

It will work assuming there is a method `getNumberOfDoors` defined as

```
public int getNumberOfDoors() {
    return this.numberOfDoors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//You Car class should look like this

public class Car {
        public String model;
        public int numberOfDoors;
        public int topSpeed;
        public int price;

// This is the Car class constructor

        public Car(String model, int numberOfDoors, int topSpeed, int price) {
            this.model = model;
            this.numberOfDoors = numberOfDoors;
            this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
            this.price = price;
        }
        }


// This is where you call the Car class. You create a new class MyCar to call my class

public class MyCar {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Car car = new Car("1990 Mustang", 4, 140, 40000);
            System.out.println(car);

// Output : 1990 Mustang, 4, 140, 40000



        }
}
```